# how to implement SNMP manager or snmptalk on vxworks 6.9

Tags: snmp, vxworks

I need to implement an SNMP manager (client) to run on a vxworks embedded single board computer, in order to monitor and control some other Linux boards, each running an SNMP agents for reading and writing local data.

Windriver supplies an example called 'snmptalk' but with no help on how to use it or how to implement it on vxworks.

Answer (score 0):

option 1.  Port snmptalk to vxworks
Windriver supplies snmptalk ( located at:  /vxworks...\demo\snmptalk...) but only for non-vxworks implementations.

option 2.
I called Windriver support and they gave me a sample of a working SNMP get and set, and it worked great.  My vxworks code can now get and set from any SNMP agent on the network.

I have now implemented an embedded web site for my client, with pages in JavaScript, which can read and write data at any SNMP data object on the network, controlled by the user web page.